# Inserted element not draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

http://jsfiddle.net/Lak13ugs/

In this sample I'm trying to rearrange the order of the list elements. I'm removing a dragged element and then inserting it after its drop target.

For some reason, after an element X is inserted, it is no longer draggable. I thought if I just called draggable() on the element it would drag for me but it isn't.

What am I typing wrong?

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>        
    <script language="javascript">


   $(document).ready(function() {

    var droppable_options = {
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var x = ui.draggable
        var y = $(this)

        x.remove()
        x.insertAfter (y)
        x.draggable( { revert: true })
      }
    } 


    $("li").draggable( { revert: true } )
    $("li").droppable( droppable_options )
}); 

    </script>

    <style>
        .ui-state-hover { border : 1px solid red }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to take out

```
x.remove();
x.draggable( { revert: true });
```

and your code will work just fine.

Your code will become

```
var droppable_options = {
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var x = ui.draggable
        var y = $(this)

        //x.remove()
        x.insertAfter (y)
        //x.draggable( { revert: true })
      }
    } 
$("li").draggable( { revert: true } )
$("li").droppable( droppable_options )
```